# Wordpress custom POST query

Tags: php, wordpress

Let's say I have two categories of posts in WordPress, "Important" and "Normal".

How would I do a posts query so that I pull out "Important posts, sorted by date, most recent first" and then "Normal posts, sorted by date, most recent first", and show 5 in total?

(Which might turn out to be 5 Important posts, or 1 Important post and then 4 Normal, or 5 Normal etc, depending on how many posts were in each category).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the WP_Query Class to extract the Posts under the "Important" Category like so:

```
    <?php
       // GET 5 IMPORTANT POSTS... MOST RECENT 1ST...
        $args               = array(
            "post_type"         => 'post',
            "category_name"     => 'Important',     //<== CHANGE THIS TO "Normal" IF YOU WANT "Normal". IF YOU WANT BOTH CHANGE TO:'Important, Normal'
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            "posts_per_page"    => 5,               // ONLY 5 IMPORTANT POSTS...
            'orderby'           => array(
                'post_date'       => 'DESC',        //<== MOST RECENT FIRST 
                "title"           => "ASC",
                'ID'              => 'ASC'
            ),
        );

        $importantPosts     = new WP_Query($args);
        // YOU CAN THEN LOOP THROUGH THE $importantPosts & DO WITH IT WHAT YOU WILL...


        // JUST ONE RECENT IMPORTANT POST...
        $args               = array(
            "post_type"         => 'post',
            "category_name"     => 'Important',     
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            "posts_per_page"    => 1,
            'orderby'           => array(
                'post_date'       => 'DESC',
                "title"           => "ASC",
                'ID'              => 'ASC'
            ),
        );
        $importantPost      = new WP_Query($args);



        // 4 RECENT NORMAL POSTS...
        $args               = array(
            "post_type"         => 'post',
            "category_name"     => 'Normal',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            "posts_per_page"    => 4,
            'orderby'           => array(
                'post_date'       => 'DESC',
                "title"           => "ASC",
                'ID'              => 'ASC'
            ),
        );
        $normalPosts        = new WP_Query($args);



        // COMBINING 1 RECENT IMPORTANT POST WITH 4 RECENT NORMAL POSTS WITHIN A NESTED LOOP:
        if($importantPost->have_posts() && $normalPosts->have_posts()):
            while ( $importantPost->have_posts() ) :
                $importantPost->the_post();
                // SINCE THE IMPORTANT POST IS JUST ONE, LET IT BE ON THE OUTER LOOP AS IT WILL JUST RUN ONLY ONCE.
                // DO ALL YOU WISH TO WITH REGARDS TO THE IMPORTANT POST HERE
                the_title();
                echo "</br>";

                while ( $normalPosts->have_posts() ) :
                    // SINCE THE NORMAL POSTS ARE 4, LET IT BE ON THE INNER LOOP.
                    // DO ALL YOU WISH TO WITH REGARDS TO THE NORMAL POSTS HERE
                    $normalPosts->the_post();
                    the_title();
                    echo "</br>";
                endwhile;

            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you might also want to go another route using conditionals to build up your Posts based on whether they are Important or Normal like so:

```
    <?php   
        // FETCH ALL EXISTING IMPORTANT POSTS ORDERED FROM NEWEST TO OLDEST
        $argsImp            = array(
            "post_type"         => 'post',
            "category_name"     => 'Important',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            "posts_per_page"    => -1,
            'orderby'           => array(
                'post_date'       => 'DESC',
                "title"           => "ASC",
                'ID'              => 'ASC'
            ),
        );
        $importantPosts     = new WP_Query($argsImp);


        // FETCH ALL EXISTING NORMAL POSTS ORDERED FROM NEWEST TO OLDEST
        $argsNorm           = array(
            "post_type"         => 'post',
            "category_name"     => 'Normal',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            "posts_per_page"    => -1,
            'orderby'           => array(
                'post_date'       => 'DESC',
                "title"           => "ASC",
                'ID'              => 'ASC'
            ),
        );
        $normalPosts        = new WP_Query($argsNorm);

        // CHECK IF WE HAVE UP TO 5 RECENT IMPORTANT POSTS.
        // IF WE DO, WE IGNORE THE NORMAL POST & ENTER OUR LOOP...
        if(count($importantPosts->posts)>=5){
            // WE KNOW WE HAVE AT LEAST 5 RECENT IMPORTANT POSTS...
            $impCounter = 0;
            while ( $importantPost->have_posts()  && $impCounter < 5) :
                $importantPost->the_post();
                // SINCE THE IMPORTANT POSTS ARE 5, WE CAN IGNORE THE NORMAL POST, THOUGH.
                // DO ALL YOU WISH TO WITH REGARDS TO THE IMPORTANT POST HERE
                the_title(); echo "</br>";
                $impCounter++;
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

        // IF OTHERWISE WE HAVE AT LEAST 1 IMPORTANT POST & 4 NORMAL POSTS,
        // WE ENTER A LOOP; GETTING 4 NORMAL POSTS & 1 IMPORTANT POST FIRST.
        }else if(count($normalPosts->posts)>=4 && count($importantPosts->posts)>=1){
            // WE KNOW WE HAVE AT LEAST A 5 RECENT NORMAL POST AND AT LEAST 1 RECENT IMPORTANT POST...
            $impCounter = 0;
            $nmlCounter = 0;
            // COMBINING 1 RECENT IMPORTANT POSTS WITH 4 NORMAL POSTS WITHIN A NESTED LOOP:
            while ( $importantPosts->have_posts()  && $impCounter < 1) :
                $importantPost->the_post();
                // SINCE THE IMPORTANT POSTS COULD BE MANY... WE USE THE $impCounter VARIABLE TO LIMIT IT TO 1 ITERATION REGARDLESS OF ITS LENGTH.
                // DO ALL YOU WISH TO WITH REGARDS TO THE IMPORTANT POST HERE
                the_title(); echo "</br>";

                while ( $normalPosts->have_posts()  && $nmlCounter < 5) :
                    // SINCE THE RECENT NORMAL POSTS ARE AT LEAST 4, LET IT BE ON THE INNER LOOP...WE USE THE $nmlCounter VARIABLE TO LIMIT IT TO 5 ITERATIONS
                    // DO ALL YOU WISH TO WITH REGARDS TO THE NORMAL POSTS HERE
                    $normalPosts->the_post();
                    the_title(); echo "</br>";

                    $nmlCounter++;
                endwhile;

                $impCounter++;
            endwhile;

        // YET, IF WE HAVE NO IMPORTANT POST AT ALL BUT UP TO 5 NORMAL POSTS,
        // AGAIN WE ENTER A LOOP: THIS TIME DEALING ONLY WITH NORMAL POSTS.
        }else if(count($normalPosts->posts)>=5 && count($importantPosts->posts)<1){
            // WE KNOW WE HAVE AT LEAST A 5 RECENT NORMAL POSTS BUT NO IMPORTANT POST...
            $nmlCounter = 0;
            while ( $normalPosts->have_posts()  && $nmlCounter < 5) :
                $normalPosts->the_post();
                // SINCE THE IMPORTANT POSTS ARE 5, WE CAN IGNORE THE NORMAL POST, THOUGH.
                // DO ALL YOU WISH TO WITH REGARDS TO THE IMPORTANT POST HERE
                the_title(); echo "</br>";
                $nmlCounter++;
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
```